# How to initiate the android app to talk with GMail account?

Tags: android, service, gmail, gmail-imap

I am developing an app which is already existing but I am developing just to learn. I am developing a GMail client app for Android. I tried with Content Observer but was unable to find the Content Provider URI for GMail Inbox. I am trying other way by setting ua a client. My client is set up, but i don't know how to instantiate this client to hit the GMail server.

Following are my code:

**GMailInbox.java**

```
package com.tyco.gmailApp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class GmailInbox extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //GmailObserver go = new GmailObserver();
        //this.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://imap.gmail.com"), true, go);

        Intent myService = new Intent(this,GMailService.class);
        myService.putExtra("user", "rj@gmail.com");
        myService.putExtra("password", "brooklyn");
        startService(myService);
    }
}
```

**GMailService.java**

```
package com.tyco.gmailApp;


import java.util.Properties;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodSession;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethod.SessionCallback;
public class GMailService extends Service
{

    private String mailhost = "imaps.gmail.com"; 
    private String user; 
    private String password; 

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent){
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        this.user = intent.getStringExtra("user"); 
        this.password = intent.getStringExtra("password");; 
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props = System.getProperties();
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
        props.setProperty("mail.imaps.host", mailhost); 
        props.put("mail.imaps.auth", "true"); 
        props.put("mail.imaps.port", "993"); 
        props.put("mail.imaps.socketFactory.port", "993"); 
        props.put("mail.imaps.socketFactory.class", 
                  "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); 
        props.put("mail.imaps.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        props.put("mail.imaps.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        props.setProperty("mail.imaps.quitwait", "false"); 


// I Don't Know what to do here



    }




}
```

I don't know what to do after collecting all info into properties object. Please suggest something.

Regards,
Rahul Jaiswal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code to connect with mail server

```
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    try{
        Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
        store.connect(mailhost, mailid,password);    
        Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        int count=folder.getUnreadMessageCount();
        Message  message[] = folder.getMessages();
        for (int i=0, n=message.length; i<n; i++) {
                System.out.println("subject " +message[i].getSubject());
        }
      }
```

Comment: I tried this code, but Session is a class defined in javax.mail package which is not supported by Android.

Comment: I added mail-1.4_1.jar into my project. Now I am getting following error:

javax.mail.MessagingException: Host is unresolved: imaps.gmail.com;
nested exception is:
java.net.SocketException: Host is unresolved: imaps.gmail.com

I resolved it by modifying my mailHost url as "imap.gmail.com" rather "imaps.gmail.com"